# Web socket doesn't open on other machines

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, server, ws

### Web soket connection error

I've got a problem with my server. It uses `express` and `express-ws` for web sockets. The problem is that this server works fine on the local host. But when i run it with the help of `ssh` (see [localhost.run](https://localhost.run/)) and access the site by the given link from another computer (through Chrome), the web socket doesn't open and the next error shows up in the console

`main.js:12 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

even though i added `cert` and `key` to the server connection. P.S. The site loads too, it's only that the socket doesn't work.

---

here is the server.js code:

```
"use strict";
const fs = require("fs");

const credentials = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./cert.pem")
};

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/Messenger"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/Login"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const server = new https.createServer(credentials);

const expressWs = require("express-ws")(app, server);//if i take the 
//second argument (server) away, it works fine on localhost:3000, but 
//with this it fires the error:

//WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Connection 
//closed before receiving a handshake response

const routes = require("./MVC/Router/router.js"); //importing route
routes(app);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("listening on port " + PORT);
});
```

---

here is the router.js:

```
   "use strict";
module.exports = function(app) {
  const database = require("../Controller/controller.js");

  // database Routes
  app.route("/").get(database.loadPage);

  app.route("/login").get(database.loginPageLoad);

  app
    .route("/signIn")
    .get(database.signInPageLoad)
    .post(database.signIn);

  app
    .route("/submitLogin")
    .post(database.loginSubmit)
    .get(database.showUsers);

  app.ws("/", database.sendmsg);
};
```

which redirects the processing flow to the next part of controller.js:

```
const CLIENTS = [];
let counter = 0;

exports.sendmsg = (ws, req) => {
  console.log(cache.get("lorem"));
  ws.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg === "connected") {
      console.log("connected");
      CLIENTS.push([ws, counter]);
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({ counter }));
      counter++;
    } else if (JSON.parse(msg).msg && JSON.parse(msg).ID) {
      CLIENTS.forEach(box => {
        if (box[1] === msg.ID) {
          console.log(`user ${box[1]} is closed`);
          box.push("closed");
          box[0].close();
        } else {
          return;
        }
      });
    } else {
      sendAll(msg);
    }
    ws.on("close", () => {
      console.log("disconnected");
      ws.close();
    });
  });
};

function sendAll(message) {
  for (let i = 0; i < CLIENTS.length; i++) {
    if (CLIENTS[i][0].readyState === 1) {
      CLIENTS[i][0].send(message);
    }
  }
}
```

The last piece of code is just what it does on the server, don't care of it too much. The problem is that the web socket doesn't get open when i enter the link from another computer. How can i solve it?

Comment: Is there any error? What is not understandable?

Comment: The web socket doesn't open on clients of other machines